# Background musicplayer and cocos2d SimpleAudioEngine

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, audio-player, mute, simpleaudioengine

I have provided mute functionality in my game. But if music player is running in background and 
when I start my game in normal mode (not in silent mode) music player is not getting paused

I have used `[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] stopBackgroundMusic];` to stop background music and playing my game music using
        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playBackgroundMusic:audiofilename loop:YES];

What should I do ?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Basically I want to pause music player (let say someone is listing songs) which is running in background when my game starts. So I can play my own game music

Answer (score 0):

There is method of `pauseBackgroundMusic` and `resumeBackgroundMusic` in `SimpleAudioEngine` class.. 
So try these methods instead of stop and play everytime. Hope this helps.. :)